# MySQL doesn't take the string value of a PHP variable (With old mysql driver)

Tags: php, mysql

I have code that looks like this:

```
    $fields = $_POST;

    $valueStrings = array();

    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        array_push($valueStrings, $key . "=" . (string) $value);
        // I also tried "$key = $value"

    }

    $updateRowQuery = "UPDATE ShoppingCart
                       SET " . implode(',', $valueStrings) . "
                       WHERE cartID = $cartID";
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid query: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list', query is: 
UPDATE ShoppingCart
SET shipToSameLocation=1,shipToSameLocation_shippingLocationID=5,shipToSameLocation_shippingMethod=test
WHERE cartID = 1405
```

If I remove the `shipToSameLocation_shippingMethod` field, it works fine. We can see that its value `test` (other values, too) don't have quotes around despite the (string) casting in the loop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL Injection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/507793

Comment: Your concatenation is already a string. Your query is also just a string. Casting a string to a string doesn't magically add quotes around it. You should also use mysqli or pdo and bind your queries.

Comment: The company website I'm working on was made in like 2005 and has me using the first MySQL driver for now. The post doesn't seem to cover that driver, but I'll check around on how to make it more secure still. Thanks

Comment: Added an edit, but I also tried simply "$key = $value"

Comment: You _must_ limit the keys to just the columns in the table.  If you don't all sorts of mayhem could happen.

Comment: MySQL thinks `test` is a column but `test` is a value: shipToSameLocation_shippingMethod=test, and I want to find out how can MySQL make test a string / put quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all values in quotes.  You're unnecessarily casting stuff there.  MySQL will figure it out for you.